# run a java -jar but restrict it to only use the terminal window and not launch a gui like it would do if you ran it via ssh

Tags: java

java -jar foobar.jar

has two different behaviors, when run locally it opens a GUI but when launched via ssh will run in the terminal.  How can I restrict the output to the terminal when running locally on Ubuntu 20 with a full desktop environment installed?

Comment: This is rather a programming question, not Ubuntu related. Our sister site Stackoverflow might have a more qualified audience for questions like this. - Besides that you might check in your java code if you are in a terminal session or not. Last not least you could pass an argument to your "main" method that indicates in which mode it should run...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar foobar.jar
```

For more info:

Visit https://github.com/bpupadhyaya/openjdk-8/blob/45af329463a45955ea2759b89cb0ebfe40570c3f/jdk/src/share/classes/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.java#L161

See details on isHeadless() function